# Get record with maximum value and show other fields from that record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to show the important dates for a manufacturing process. There are 10 rooms performing the same process. Each time the process starts over a new cycle number is assigned. I want to show the important dates for the current (i.e. maximum) cycle in each room.

So far I have put together a query that will show the important dates for the maximum cycle number overall (my code is below), but I want to add an additional criterion so that I see the information for the maximum cycle number in each room

```
SELECT 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[rm], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[bpr], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[plug_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[trig_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[flush_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[harv_date]
FROM dbo_batch_overview5
WHERE ((([dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc])=(SELECT Max([dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc]) 
FROM [dbo_batch_overview5]
)));
```

I think I need to add a GROUP BY statement to specify that I want to see the maximum cycle number for each unique entry in the room [rm] field, here is the code with my attempt at the statement I think I need included:

```
  SELECT 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[rm], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[bpr], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[plug_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[trig_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[flush_date], 
     [dbo_batch_overview5].[harv_date]
FROM dbo_batch_overview5
WHERE ((([dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc])=(SELECT Max([dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc]) 
FROM [dbo_batch_overview5]
GROUP BY [dbo_batch_overview5].[rm]
)));
```

When I try the above code I get an error saying that my subquery is returning more than one value. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

As requested, here is some sample data

```
rm  cyc bpr         clone_date  plug_date   trig_date   harv_date
1   13  20161031-OP 10/31/2016  11/16/2016  11/22/2016  1/12/2017
1   13  20161101-EV 11/1/2016   11/16/2016  11/22/2016  1/13/2017
1   13  20161031-CG 10/31/2016  11/16/2016  11/22/2016  1/13/2017
1   13  20161101-CB 11/1/2016   11/16/2016  11/22/2016  1/12/2017
1   13  20161031-VO 10/31/2016  11/16/2016  11/22/2016  1/13/2017
1   14  20170104-CG 1/4/2017    1/23/2017   1/28/2017   
1   14  20170104-CB 1/4/2017    1/23/2017   1/28/2017   
1   14  20170106-AV 1/6/2017    1/23/2017   1/28/2017   
1   14  20170106-MN 1/6/2017    1/23/2017   1/28/2017   
2   7   20150925-ST 9/25/2015   10/10/2015  10/19/2015  12/16/2015
2   7   20150924-AL 9/24/2015   10/10/2015  10/19/2015  12/16/2015
2   7   20150924-EA 9/24/2015   10/10/2015  10/19/2015  12/21/2015
2   7   20150928-LM 9/28/2015   10/10/2015  10/19/2015  12/22/2015
2   7   20150928-HM 9/28/2015   10/10/2015  10/19/2015  12/19/2015
2   8   20151214-CG 12/14/2015  12/30/2015  1/7/2016    3/14/2016
2   8   20151214-RM 12/14/2015  12/30/2015  1/7/2016    3/15/2016
2   8   20151215-CB 12/15/2015  12/30/2015  1/7/2016    3/8/2016
```

In the above example, I would only want to see the records associated with cycle 14 in room 1 and cycle 8 in room 2

Comment: Although I would advise joining to a subselect, this is probably what you are looking for - ```WHERE ((([dbo_batch_overview5].[cyc]) in (SELECT Max...```

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave I couldn't figure out how to use dbfiddle, but I added sample data to my original question above

Comment: @Anand Can you specify what the remainder of the line of code you suggested would look like? As it stands I don't know where to go from what you've suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this solve your problem?

```
SELECT 
 a.[rm], 
 a.[cyc], 
 a.[bpr], 
 a.[plug_date], 
 a.[trig_date], 
 a.[flush_date], 
 a.[harv_date]
FROM dbo_batch_overview5 a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Max([cyc]) AS maxcyc,
                       rm as rm2
                FROM [dbo_batch_overview5]
                GROUP BY [rm])c
        ON a.rm = c.rm2 AND a.cyc = c.maxcyc
```

Comment: I don't think CTE is supported in MS Access. I would move that query inside the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @trincot Sorry about that.  I altered the query to not use a CTE.  Does this work?

Comment: @trincot Thanks.  I didn't realize you weren't the one that asked the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, I get the following error: "Circular reference caused by alias 'cyc' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: @DylanHarding I changed the aliases in the query.  Let's see if that works out.

Comment: It worked! Thanks C B ! I also have a better understanding of how Aliases work now, I am very grateful